# Rails - Retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have read so much about Rails in the past week in the process of trying to learn it. The problem is when I need something I find it difficult to recall where I read it! ha ha

I have two models: Guest and Booking where Guests has_many Bookings. Therefore the Booking model has a guest_id field included.

I would like to retrieve all the booking data and the guest data and display in a view as one object. I know I have seen a simple solution to this (in the Rails doc I think) that does just this.

At the moment I'm doing the following in my BookingsController:

```
@bookings = Booking.all
```

and in my associated view I have:

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <p><%= booking.id %></p>
  <p><%= booking.email %></p> //this does not work as email is in guests table!!!
<% end %>
```

but how can I get the linked Guest table included too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your booking belongs to guest

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest
  ...
end
```

you can first include guest to avoid [n+1 queries](http://matteo.vaccari.name/aw/the-n+1-queries-problem-and-rails)

```
@bookings = Booking.includes(:guest).all
```

and then in view, traverse the association

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <p><%= booking.id %></p>
  <p><%= booking.guest.email %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Fantastic - and went to extra length to show me example. Cheers for the help

Answer (score 1):

In your bookings controller:

`@bookings = Booking.includes(:guest).all`